# About memory management in OpenCV

Tags: c, opencv, memory-management, iplimage

I'm sorry if this may seem like a silly question...
I've a doubt about cvLoadImage in OpenCV:

```
IplImage *frame;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++)
{
    frame = cvLoadImage(filename.c_str());  
    // do something...
}
```

For each call of `cvLoadImage` is a new `IplImage` stored in memory? Is the old variable pointed by `frame` released from heap after the override?

Furthermore, when I try to release an image as follow...

```
IplImage *frame;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++)
{
    if (frame != NULL)
        cvReleaseImage(&frame);

    frame = cvLoadImage(filename.c_str());  
    // do something...
}
```

Why doesn't this solution work (bad memory access)?
Best regards, Vi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, memory allocated by cvLoadImage. Error appears because you not initialized frame in the beginning. It must be initialized by zero, or NULL.